# Why is R2 of a prediction lower than another prediction while RMSE is lower too?

Tags: regression, prediction

I have a regression problem with two objective variables or outputs (named E & r). I made a model for every objective separately. I used Gaussian processes regression.

I obtained prediction for both objectives as below (error bar shows standard deviation):

[image]

[image]

Title of the plots shows R2 & RMSE of prediction. There is a categorical variable in dataset (Mixer) which has two values (50L, 2400L), shown by different colors on the plot.

Following, I calculate R2 & RMSE separately for every Mixer (shown in the legend):

[image]

[image]

As you can see, for objective E, RMSE of Mixer 2400L (blue color) is less than RMSE of Mixer 50L (orange color). But, its R2 is very low which is surprising for me. I expect that when RMSE is lower, R2 should be higher.

And for objective r, RMSE of both Mixers are almost similar. But, R2 of Mixer 2400L is much lower.

I have only one assumption about this phenomenon. Reason of low R2 is because of lower No. of samples for Mixer 2400L.

No. of Observations:

- Total : 119
- Mixer 50L : 106
- Mixer 2400L : 13

If you have any idea. please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is simply because the RMSE tells us how well a regression model can predict the value of the response variable in absolute terms while R2 tells us how well a model can predict the value of the response variable in percentage terms.

It is all about the scale. Scale of R2 values can vary significantly while RMSE is just raw error distance